# React HashRouter issue in New Edge browser

Tags: reactjs, iis, microsoft-edge, router

My react app uses HashRouter for client side routing. No server side routing and this is hosted on IIS. The # path get lost on Edge, the first time(sso). But works on consecutive tries on the same page or different page (as long as the first page is open) Page refresh works fine as well. So basically the HashRouter works in general, just not the first time on a fresh Edge browser

On First time - location.hash - ""

On Refresh - location.hash -  #/pathname

```
   <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>
```

Can be recreated in Chrome with clearing browser data

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? In [this doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter), it says <HashRouter> is only intended to support legacy browsers, we encourage you to configure your server to work with <BrowserHistory> instead. So unless you have a specific need to support old browsers, then you should use [<BrowserHistory>](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-history#react-history--) which uses the HTML5 [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

Comment: I dig further and found what is causing the issue. I will update the Question

Comment: Great! Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is widely experienced by other developers who use # segment in the URL. The Browser preserves the #fragment but after the SSO (single sign on) the returning URL ignore the hash segment ( because it use # segment to attach the authorization token). The following link explains and suggest solutions.

https://chevtek.io/how-to-persist-url-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect/

I did the following 
I used # (react HashRouter) for client side routing. what I did was append the landing page in the url as one of the querystrings and later get the value from the URL and reattach to the current URL hash (window.location.hash)